# What does g++ / gcc do when asked to link against .a files?

Tags: c, linker, libraries

I'm reading a tutorial about C development with the SDL library on MingW and Windows. (The tutorial is actually about C++ but I'm assuming installation and building is the same).

The tutorial gives the following command for building the program:

```
g++ 01_hello_SDL.cpp -IC:\mingw_dev_lib\include\SDL2 -LC:\mingw_dev_lib\lib -w -Wl,-subsystem,windows -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -o 01_hello_SDL
```

1. In this command we use `-L` and `-l` to tell `g++` where to find `.a` files (*not* `.DLL` or `.so` files) for linking. However, as far as I understand - this command is supposed to *dynamically* link the library. And as we know, `.a` files are *static* library files. What am I missing?
2. Why are we not linking with the `.DLL` file of the library, but instead we link with these `.a` files? When executing, the `.DLL` file will have to be present near the executable, but the `.a` won't have to as far as I understand. Again, what am I missing?

Comment: The `-l` command is supposed to _search_ for the library. It can search for a static or a shared library.

Answer (score 0):

`-l` is not only for dynamic libraries. It can also be used to link static libraries.

On Linux, it is normal to directly link with a .so file (equivalent to a .dll). On Windows, it is still possible to do this (I think), but it is more normal to link with a .lib file called an *import library*, which wraps the .dll (you link to the .lib and the .lib links to the .dll). Since you are not using the Microsoft toolchain, it's possible that your toolchain still uses import libraries, but calls them .a files instead of .lib files.